# C# Windows Maintain Hidden values in ListBox?

Tags: c#

How I Can maintain `Hidden values in ListBox` ?

My Requirement List is I want to maintain `IDs Vs. Name in the ListBox` without maintaining any other Generic List ?

Name will be visible and Ids will be hidden.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to bind/show in your listBox. You mentioned an unmanaged structure (c++) in one of your comments. Pls add some more code to your question.

Comment: I am binding my Listbox with one of the structure which i am getting from C++.Its normal string data which i am adding to ListBox.Now the only problem is Pairing for Ids Vs. Name

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
listBox1.DataSource = ds;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text to show";
listBox1.ValueMember = "value you retrieve from the code";
```

Comment: Sorry, Forget to mention my data is coming from a unmanaged Structure(C++) so i cannot assign that to datasource.

Comment: Better if the members are assigned before assigning the `DataSource`

Comment: @user662285 Please edit the question and add it to *My Requirement* list

Comment: Using above code gives Error : "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource"